# Trigger function on new image load that matches selectors with an If/else statement

Tags: jquery, event-handling, callback, slider

I've hit a wall and need some guidance getting this to work. I preface this with I'm a noob with jQuery and any way that I can write what I have already written better, or more streamlined is certainly welcome.

Currently I have 2 sliders on the page. Each image has a unique class. When the user clicks on the image slider the image slides in and the class "activeSlide" is added to it. What I would like to have happen is when the user clicks a slider and an image loads that matches another image, an alert pops up. There will be different image combinations that will trigger the popup, and if no matches, nothing happens.

Currently with the below code it works, though fires the alert after the images match and the user clicks the slider again. The ideal would be that the user click an image slider, the new image loads, and if it's a match will call the event handler to have the alert pop up.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="top" class="Slider">
    <img class="rsImg" src="images/tShirtRed.png" alt="tShirtRed" />
    <img class="rsImg" src="images/tShirtGreen.png" alt="tShirtGreen" />
    <img class="rsImg" src="images/tShirtRed.png" alt="tShirtRed" />
</div>


<div id="bottom" class="Slider">
    <img class="classBottom1" src="images/image5.png" alt="" />
    <img class="classBottom2" src="images/image6.png" alt="" />
    <img class="classBottom3" src="images/image6.png" alt="" />
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery:

```
var sliderInstance = $("#chest").data('royalSlider');

    sliderInstance.ev.on('rsAfterSlideChange', function() {
            if (($('#chest .rsActiveSlide img').attr('alt') == 'tShirtGreen') && ($('#legs .rsActiveSlide img').attr('alt') == 'jeansGreen')) {
            alert('Your message');
            } else {
            //Do nothing
            }
    });
```

My Dev environment is here: http://beingproperties.com/match-game/

Thank you in advance and appreciate any input. Cheers 
-Chris

Comment: A question of your code, how can an img being .classTop1 and .classBottom1 at the same time?

Comment: There are 2 seperate sliders with different images/classes.

Comment: I knew that, but that's two separate slides, but an img can't be at both places at the SAME time.

Comment: Are you removing the `activeClass` from the images after the alert has been shown? Or is the problem that the alert is shown if either of a successfully matched pair is clicked for a second time - if so, you should add a clas like `successfulMatch` to them, and then check for the presence of that before showing the alert.

Comment: @deerchao I *think* his code adds `activeClass` to the "correct" image in each `Slider` element, so `$('.activeClass')` will match both elements, and `.is()` will succeed if either element matches the selector. @Centinel3 it would be very, very helpful to provide a working jsfiddle.net demo showing the problem.

Comment: @KelvinMackay setting up a fiddle would be a PIA with this I believe. You can check out my dev environment here for the rapid prototype I'm working on (http://beingproperties.com/match-game/). This is working when a match happens with a green outfit, thoguh what I need to happen is the alert pops up after the matching image slides in and is a match on the screen. Right now what happens is that a match happens, and the alert is triggered after you click a second time (which slides the next image in).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with some help from the developer at RoyalSlider :[Royal Slider](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/)

The jQuery needed to be after the slider initialization and within the document.ready() function.

I also needed to rearrange the function I was trying to call as well. See above for the fixed code.

Thanks again to Dmitry at RoyalSlider!
-Chris